# find security bugs does not scan groovy files

Tags: java, groovy, findbugs, find-sec-bugs

In our project, we use both Groovy and Java classes. We are using the find-sec-bugs plugin 1.4.3 with FindBugs 3.0.1 to scan the source code.

The security bugs from Groovy classes are not reported by the plugin. Java classes are properly scanned. The [project page](https://github.com/h3xstream/find-sec-bugs) clearly says the plugin works with Groovy.

For this testing, I copied the following [vulnerable code](http://h3xstream.github.io/find-sec-bugs/bugs.htm), compiled the source code, and ran the scan on that.

```
String generateSecretToken() {
    Random r = new Random();
    return Long.toHexString(r.nextLong());
}
```

Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Do you use gradle or maven? Both tools have plugins for findbugs and it seems to run properly.

Comment: Thanks Opal. I am using the FindBugs UI. It scans the both groovy and java source code properly. The problem is with find-sec-bugs plugin. This plugin scans the java code properly. But, it ignores the groovy code.

Comment: @nr673 Please open a ticket here : https://github.com/h3xstream/find-sec-bugs/issues (copy-paste your question)

Comment: @h3xStream Sorry for the delayed response. Reported the issue as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have proper analysis, you need to activate **static compiling**. Otherwise, the analyzer will not see any method calls.

**build.gradle**

```
compileGroovy {
    groovyOptions.configurationScript = file("gradle/config.groovy")
}
```

**gradle/config.groovy**

```
withConfig(configuration) {
     ast(groovy.transform.CompileStatic)
}
```

A full recipe is available here:
https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs-demos/tree/master/groovy-simple